# ValidationException in lambda API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following code:

```
function updateComplaint(complaints) {
        return API.put("kleen", `/Complaint/${state.complaint[0].id}`, {
            body: state.complaint[0]
        });
    }
```

but when ever I run it, I get the following error:

[image]

This is the table I am trying to edit:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and what should my code look like?

Code for my API:

```
import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";
import { success, failure } from "./libs/response-lib";

export async function main(event, context) {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const params = {
        TableName: process.env.tableName,
        // 'Key' defines the partition key and sort key of the item to be updated
        // - 'userId': Identity Pool identity id of the authenticated user
        // - 'noteId': path parameter
        Key: {
            typeName: event.requestContext.identity.typeName,
            id: event.pathParameters.cognitoIdentityId
        },
        // 'UpdateExpression' defines the attributes to be updated
        // 'ExpressionAttributeValues' defines the value in the update expression
        UpdateExpression: "SET adminComment = :adminComment, updatedAt = :updatedAt",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":updatedAt": Date.now() || null,
            ":adminComment": data.adminComment || null
        },
        // 'ReturnValues' specifies if and how to return the item's attributes,
        // where ALL_NEW returns all attributes of the item after the update; you
        // can inspect 'result' below to see how it works with different settings
        ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
    };

    try {
        await dynamoDbLib.call("update", params);
        return success({ status: true });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return failure({ status: false });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not an issue with AWS lambda. Are you using dynamodb? If yes, can you share that code?

Comment: @ArunSelin Added the code for my API that connects with my DynamoDB table